# How to split a dictionary keys at "_" and create two dimensional table?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {"a_1":20,"b_1":5,"a_2":8,"b_2":7}
```

I want to split the dictionary at underlines ("_") and create a table like this:

[image]

I try to split keys with:

```
[key.split('_') for key in dict.keys()]
```

i could not use the result in pandas. How do i create the table using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your case you can do pass the dict to `pd.Series` , then `split` the `index` , and `unstack` . Notice  : do not name dict as 'dict'

```
s = pd.Series(d)
s.index=s.index.str.split('_').map(tuple)
s = s.unstack(level=0)
s
    a  b
1  20  5
2   8  7
```

Comment: `Index.str.split` supports going directly to MultiIndex with `expand=True`. Could be `s.index = s.index.str.split('_', expand=True)` instead of `map(tuple)`